# How to install/update an application with gpo without restarting the terminal

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, installation, windows-10

I have an application that requires regular updates applied through GPO.
This application does not require restarting the PC to install or update.
How can I create a GPO to install this application without a restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816102/how-to-use-group-policy-to-remotely-install-software-in-windows-server) says that the program is installed when the computer starts.

Deploying a software via GPO (especially if you need to update it on a regular basis) is not a best practice.

You should consider using something like SCCM. However, if you have very few applications to deploy, you can still use GPO, in that case you can create a scheduled task and start you own powershell to perform the upgrade.

Here is a walkthrough that can help you creating a scheduled task via GPO:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kaushika/2015/04/26/the-startup-script-is-dead/

based on you needs, you can create an Immediate Task instead (it's a scheduled task that will run as soon as possible on client computers) and check "Apply once and do not reapply" (available in the "Common" tab).